# Simplify $ \frac{4\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)} - \frac{4\sin^2(x)}{(1-\cos(x))^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Spent any hour trying, but can't simplify this formula.

$$ \frac{4\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)} - \frac{4\sin^2(x)}{(1-\cos(x))^2}$$

Calculator CAS tells me the result should be $\dfrac{4}{\cos(x) - 1}$, but I can't seem to do it myself. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: start with the common denominator of $(1- \cos(x))^2$.  Write the first fraction in terms of this denominator.  Add the fractions.  Simplify.

Comment: Isn't there a missing bracket in the second denominator?

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for your help. Forgot how I could split (1-cosx^2) into (1-cosx) and (1+cosx).

Comment: @Mason Yeah that's right what am I thinking. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x=(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)$$

therefore

$$\frac{4\cos x}{1-\cos x } - \frac{4\sin^2 x}{(1-\cos x)^2}=\frac{4\cos x}{1-\cos x} - \frac{4(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}{(1-\cos x)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to algebra and completely forgot I could simplify it that way.

Comment: @MaxwellStone As a suggestion for clearness don't use $\sin (x)$ or $\cos (x)$ but simply $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. Use parenthesis only for $\sin (f(x))$ or similar expressions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @MaxwellStone You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @gimusi It is certainly *common* to see $\sin x$ rather than $\sin(x)$.  This is a *convention* which is not unusual, and is typically understood.  That is not the same as it being *more clear*.  Indeed, I fail to see how one could seriously argue that it really is more clear to write $\sin x$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm referring mainly to the visualization indeed $$\frac{4\sin^2 x}{(1-\cos x)^2}$$ can be used instead of $$\frac{4\sin^2(x)}{(1-\cos(x))^2}$$ without any loss of information.

Comment: Bad habit, perhaps, to get into. (Omitting parentheses). How about omitting parentheses in the function $f(x) = \sin x \ln  x$?  Is that a good idea to leave off parentheses from the $'x'$ if what is meant is $\sin(x) \ln x$, and not $\sin (x \ln x)$?  Just don't overgeneralize in comments to OPs about best practices.

Comment: @amWhy You are enlarging the discussion beyond my initial suggestion. I'm not saying to do not use parentheses at all, I'm claiming to omit them when they don't need at all.

Comment: For a beginner, safer to suggest keeping parentheses surrounding the arguments of each function.  Nuances can be learned later.  Just surprised that you'd comment to discourage their use, when they cause no harm.

Comment: @gimusi You suggested that you omit the parentheses *in the interest of clarity*.  The parentheses are, indeed, often omitted.  This does not mean that it is more clear.  Personally, I would *always* advise students to retain the parentheses.  This emphasizes that $\sin$ is a function which takes an argument.  I would also suggest that students use the notation $\sin(x)^2$ rather than $\sin^2(x)$, as $\sin^2(x)$ can be interpreted to mean $\sin(\sin(x))$, and is ambiguous when the inverse trig functions show up.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm referring to that specific case that is I suggest to use $\sin x$ insted of $\sin(x)$, I'm not giving general rules, it is only a minor suggestion.

Comment: If you want to suggest that a student omit the parentheses because it is a common convention (it is) and reduces some visual clutter (this is debatable), great!  But justifying it in the name of clarity is, frankly, disingenuous.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Maybe I've used "clearness" in  a not proper way indeed I'm referring to a better visualization.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{4\cos(x)(1-\cos(x))-4\sin^2(x)}{(1-\cos(x))^2}=\dfrac{4(\cos x-1)}{(1-\cos(x))^2}=\dfrac{-4}{1-\cos(x)}=\dfrac{4}{\cos(x) - 1}$.

(Using $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$).